# How to implement a dictionary using a Map

Tags: list, dictionary, elixir

I'm trying to implement a dictionary but the Map.put function is not adding the new element to the map instead it is giving me a new map with the last (key, value} inserted I also tried Map.put_new it did not work

```ruby
def someFunction(array) do

    dict = %{}

    Enum.each(array, fn item ->
        if (Map.has_key?(dict, item)) do
            dict = %{dict | item => (dict[item] + 1)}
        else
            dict = Map.put(dict , item, 1)
        end
    end)

end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way elixir does variable scopes, you can't set `dict` from inside your `Enum.each/2`. Instead what you need to do is pass `dict` as an accumulator while enumerating `array`.

```
dict =
  Enum.reduce(array, %{}, fn item, dict ->
    if (Map.has_key?(dict, item)) do
      %{dict | item => (dict[item] + 1)}
    else
      Map.put(dict , item, 1)
    end
  end)
```

You can also use `Map.update/4` to improve your reducer.

```
dict = Enum.reduce(array, %{}, fn item, dict -> Map.update(dict, item, 1, &(&1 + 1)) end)
```

But there's actually a built-in function since Elixir 1.10, [Enum.frequencies/1](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#frequencies/1).

```
dict = Enum.frequencies(array)
```

Comment: `Enum.frequencies/1`, nice. The [implementation](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.11.0/lib/elixir/lib/enum.ex#L1127) is worth checking too.